# What is the nature of this depiction? Which Gods are presented here?

Tags: gods, identification-request

[image]

I found this in an apartment I recently moved into. I've been interested in Hinduism and Buddhism for a number of years but have close to no knowledge of the traditions (I have taken some university courses). I was just wondering which gods are depicted here and what exactly is going on. I suspect the figure at the bottom may be Kali because of the ornaments she's holding, but also I've never seen Kali on a horse so I'm probably wrong. If this question should be directed on a different site please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

First, this picture has nothing to do with Hinduism (Sanatana Dharma). This is a Buddhist picture of Tara and her 21 forms. If you count them, leaving out the central figure and the figure on horse below the central figure, there are 21 others around. A similar depiction of the same image in color is

[image]

There is also recognition in some schools of Buddhism of twenty-one Tārās. A practice text entitled In Praise of the 21 Tārās, is recited during the morning in all four sects of Tibetan Buddhism ( Refer to Wiki Pages [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tara_(Buddhism)) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praises_to_the_Twenty-One_Taras)). The list of names of 21 Taras can be found [here](http://www.abuddhistlibrary.com/Buddhism/A%20-%20Tibetan%20Buddhism/Subjects/Tantra/Practices-%20(Sadhanas%20and%20commentaries)/Tara/Tara%20-%20The%20Mother%20of%20All%20Buddhas/Tara,%20the%20Mother%20of%20all%20Buddhas.htm) and [here](http://www.rigpawiki.org/index.php?title=Twenty-one_Taras). The Praise to 21 Taras is [here](https://fpmt.org/wp-content/uploads/prayers/21tarasltrrdr.pdf).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry if I have offended anyone by thinking it is Hindu.

Comment: That is okay, one should know what's ours and also what is not ours. It meant no offense at all.